# Centrino Wireless-N 2230 not working after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, 16.04, intel-wireless, centrino

I have a laptop HP Pavilion dv6 which I upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04, now the wifi network does not work.

Currently the wireless button (F12) is lit blue so it looks like normal, but I cannot enable wifi nor I can scan networks.

This used to work well with 14.04.

I have performed the following checkings but I am completely lost.

Check the connection:

```
$ nmcli dev
DISPOSITIVO        TIPO      ESTADO         CONEXIÓN           
eth0               ethernet  conectado      Wired connection 1 
58:55:CA:E6:8C:D0  bt        desconectado   --                 
wlan0              wifi      no disponible  --                 
lo                 loopback  sin gestión    --
```

Check the wireless adapter is recognized:

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network DESACTIVADO   
       descripción: Interfaz inalámbrica
       producto: Centrino Wireless-N 2230
       fabricante: Intel Corporation
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       nombre lógico: wlan0
       versión: c4
       serie: 68:5d:43:0e:80:35
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuración: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-34-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       recursos: irq:31 memoria:d4500000-d4501fff
  *-network
       descripción: Ethernet interface
       producto: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:0b:00.0
       nombre lógico: eth0
       versión: 07
       serie: 08:2e:5f:73:2a:4f
       tamaño: 1Gbit/s
       capacidad: 1Gbit/s
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuración: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 ip=10.93.0.163 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       recursos: irq:27 ioport:2000(size=256) memoria:d4404000-d4404fff memoria:d4400000-d4403fff
```

Check the state of wireless devices:

```
$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
3: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Check driver when loading:

```
$ dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[   23.776926] iwlwifi 0000:0a:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[   24.119427] iwlwifi 0000:0a:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm
[   24.544331] iwlwifi 0000:0a:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[   24.544337] iwlwifi 0000:0a:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[   24.544340] iwlwifi 0000:0a:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[   24.544344] iwlwifi 0000:0a:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 2230 BGN, REV=0xC8
[   24.544455] iwlwifi 0000:0a:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   24.551979] iwlwifi 0000:0a:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[   25.210759] iwlwifi 0000:0a:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
```

Update file /etc/default/crda to set the correct region code:

```
REGDOMAIN=ES
```

Comment: Does the result of: `rfkill list all` change at all as you press the F12 button? Is it possibly Fn+F12?

Comment: Could you please paste a before and after here and give us the link? http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: @chili555 Here it is: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23116021/ I must add that I cannot revert the led to blue by pressing again F12.

Comment: Please try an experiment. From the terminal: `sudo modprobe -r hp-wmi` and then: `rfkill list all` Any improvement? If so, I will propose a solution.

Comment: Yes, indeed, after that only 2 wireless connections exist: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23116834/. It has even connected to a wifi network at wlan0. I cannot see the list of available wifi networks though.

Comment: @chili555 You maybe proposing to blacklist module hp-wmi on startup?

Comment: Exactly. Please try the solution in my answer and let me know the result.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you blacklist the helper module:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist hp-wmi"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Reboot and tell us the result.

Comment: After that, wireless key is lit orange, only a device is listed: $ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
and i have no wifi.

Comment: I have found the following workaround: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23153750/

Comment: Does anybody have ideas on how to actually solve this issue?

Comment: I suggest that you file a bug against *hp-wmi* here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/ You might also try the live DVD or USB for Ubuntu 16.10 to see if the behavior is improved.